# Move the location of the XYZ pivot point on a mesh in UDK

Tags: 3d-meshes, udk, unreal

When working with any mesh, you get an XYZ point somewhere on it. If you just want to move the mesh in any direction, it doesn't matter where this point is located.

However, I want to rotate a door. This requires the point of rotation to be very specific. I can't find anywhere how to change the location of the point. Can anyone help?

EDIT: solved, to change the pivot point, right click on the mesh, go to "Pivot" and move it. Then right click again and this time select "Save PrePivot to Pivot"

Comment: if you answered your question, put it in the answer and mark accept.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know that is in the model itself. You have to open that model on whatever editing package you used to make the door in the first place and move the pivot there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that the pivot is set based on where the model is from the origin in world space not model space.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the statick mesh you wish to alter the pivot point
In the properties box that apears click the display tab
click on pre pivot and you can then alter the pivot point using X Y Z coordinates

Answer (score -1):

right click on the model. from the context menu select Pivot > Move Here (Snapped)